# CSS zoom does not work for a <img> in <a>, in iOS 8 Mobile Safari

Tags: css, mobile, zooming, mobile-safari, ios8

Using `zoom: 0.5;`, image gets rendered in 0.5x size when not inside `<a>` tag, but in 1x size when inside `<a>` tag.

This occurred with iOS 8 GM (iPhone 5 simulator of Xcode 6 GM, and iPad mini).

This did not occur with iOS 7.1.2 (iPhone 5) and iOS 7.0 (iPhone 5 simulator of Xcode 6 GM).

Here is an example : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/379843/ios8csszoom/test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <img src="star-on@2x.png" style="border: 1px solid blue; zoom: 0.5;"/>

        <a href="#">
            <img src="star-on@2x.png" style="border: 1px solid blue; zoom: 0.5;"/>
        </a>

        <hr>

        <img src="star-on@2x.png" style="border: 1px solid blue; -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);"/>

        <a href="#">
            <img src="star-on@2x.png" style="border: 1px solid blue; -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);"/>
        </a>
    </body>
</html>
```

`-webkit-transform` is functioning on iOS 8, but I don' want to use this, because even though the image is rendered in 0.5x size, the space consumed by the `<img>` tag is 1x size.

Any workarounds?

Comment: This also occurs in Safari 8 on OS X Yosemite Beta.

Comment: that is new iOS bug. Hope to be fixed ASAP, because changing all of zoomed anchors to some other tag is unacceptable...

Comment: This bug is now fixed in iOS 8.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although not ideal, this is how I've coped with the problem:

- Replace anchors with another element (div or span depending on block/inline)
- Give each element a shared class name
- Either leave the href, or, add a data-href property with the href
- On a high level, have an event listener bind to all elements with your class name
- Event listener reads href and then triggers routing/controller logic appropriate for your framework

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/z5crh05a/

```
$(".fauxLink").on("click", function(e) {

        var href = $(e.currentTarget).attr("href");

        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();            

        // navigation logic here
        alert("Navigate to: "+href);

    });

});
```

Hopefully the issue in Safari is fixed in a future iOS update.

Comment: I worked around with a different method, which could only be used with a webapp framework (I will post later).
Your solution seem to work, for any environment :)

Answer (score 3):

By default -webkit-transform on Safari and MobileSafari has an origin “center center”, which means the parent container will be the same size as if not scaled.

Adjust this by setting this to “top left” using:

```
-webkit-transform-origin 0 0;
```

Whole solution would then be (with IE9+, FF, Chrome and Safari/MobileSafari support):

```
        transform: scale(0.5);
    -ms-transform: scale(0.5);
   -mos-transform: scale(0.5);
-webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
        transform-origin: 0 0;
    -ms-transform-origin: 0 0;
   -mos-transform-origin: 0 0;
-webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
```

Comment: This would still keep the space though wouldn't it? So there would be a gap underneath it of the same height again - how do you get around that problem?

Answer (score 2):

I transform these pictures with scale.

```
-webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
-moz-transform: scale(0.5);
-o-transform: scale(0.5);
transform: scale(0.5);
```

this also works for ios but you have to reposition your pics after that!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround, but can only be used with a webapp framework.
I was using CakePHP, and was using a helper method to output all img tags, so I overrided that method so that it would output width and height attributes, and quit using the css zoom.

I used getimagesize of GD to get the width and height.
http://php.net/manual/ja/function.getimagesize.php

Answer (score 0):

Rather than changing your markup, you can just resize the images using a little bit of javascript.

Here's a working snippet (using jQuery) of what I'm currently using on my WordPress blog:

```
var dmblog  = {

    // [TRUNCATED]

    // ! dmblog.imgZoomResize
    imgZoomResize        : function(element) {
        var zoom = element.css('zoom');
        element.width(element[0].naturalWidth*zoom);
        element.height(element[0].naturalHeight*zoom);
    },

    // ! dmblog.retinaImagesResize
    retinaImagesResize  : function() {
        $('.post .entry-content img, .comment .comment-content img').each(function(){
            dmblog.imgZoomResize($(this));
            // set a handler on the resize event to resize the retina images
            var $w          = $(window),
                namespace   = $(this)[0].id.replace('#','.'),
                element     = $(this),
                handler     = function() {
                    dmblog.imgZoomResize(element);
                };
            $w.bind('resize'+namespace, handler);
        });
    }
};

// [TRUNCATED]

// ! for single posts, load some scripts
if ($('body').hasClass('single'))
{
    // [TRUNCATED]

    // resize retina images
    dmblog.retinaImagesResize();
}
```

Using this workaround, there's no need to change your css, the anchor tags, nor any of your markup, just add a little bit of javascript to resize the images.

I'm using CSS media queries to set the CSS zoom to 1 on large screens, and to 0.5 on smaller screens. Even though the zoom value doesn't work anymore, it still reports as 0.5 in jQuery. Since it's a responsive design, I added a handler on the window resize event to automatically resize the image up/down whenever the zoom value is changed (responding to CSS media queries).

If you're not using media queries to responsively change the CSS zoom value though, then the amount of javascript you'll need (without the handler) is much less.